# How to fix '/bin/bash: th: command not found' error in torch on Google Colaboratory

Tags: lua, torch, google-colaboratory

Please, I need to run `!th luafile.lua` in colab.
After installing torch following [this link](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_), I run `!th`but obtained this error:

```
/bin/bash: th: command not found
```

I `ls`into `/root/torch/install/bin`. No `th*` is present:

```
json2lua*  lua2json*  luajit*  luarocks*  luarocks-admin*  mdcat*
```

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hard but easy

**Clone the Torch repo (forked to work with CUDA 10).**

`!git clone https://github.com/nagadomi/distro.git torch --recursive`

**Install Torch.**

```
import os
os.chdir('./torch/')
!bash install-deps
!./install.sh
```

**Activate Torch.**

`!. ./install/bin/torch-activate`

**Make sure the installation worked.**

`!./install/bin/th`

Result:

```
  ______             __   |  Torch7 
 /_  __/__  ________/ /   |  Scientific computing for Lua. 
  / / / _ \/ __/ __/ _ \  |  Type ? for help 
 /_/  \___/_/  \__/_//_/  |  https://github.com/torch 
                          |  http://torch.ch 

th> ^C
```